# How do I get a simple sound to play in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I want to play a simple sound. I'm not getting any exceptions, but the sound just isn't playing

```
<MediaElement Source="sounds/Laser.mp3" Volume="1"  AutoPlay="True" x:Name="Laser" />
```

Calling the Play() method doesn't work either.

```
Laser.Play();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that the Build action needs to be set to "Resource". But [here](http://silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/25/tip-of-the-day-22-how-to-add-sound-effects-music-and-video-to-your-silverlight-app.aspx) is an excellent article that explains how to add sound (Silverlight 2).

Comment: Haha. That site is where I got the code that isn't working. All my sound files are set to resource. Mabye it's my computer...

Comment: But... It works for a friend of mine, so I guess it's just my computer